# Simulated long process using a timer

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

I'm trying to create a routine to sequentially execute a series of test processes. I can't even figure out how to create a simulation function for a long process. It uses a timer to ensure sequential order (one process doesn't start until the previous one finishes).  I've tried many things, here is an example of what seems like it might work...

```
async function someLongProcess(myInfoStr) {
    // Some async process that takes time
    console.log(myInfoStr + ": Process Starting");
    setTimeout(()=>{
        console.log(myInfoStr + ": Process Finishing");
        return myInfoStr + ": Process Finished";
    }, 1000);
}

someLongProcess("Test A").then(
    function(value) { console.log(value) },
    function(error) { console.log("Oh oh!: " + error) }
);
```

The result I wanted: "Test A: Process Starting", "Test A: Process Finishing", "Test A: Process Finished".

The result I got: "Test A: Process Starting", "undefined", "Test A: Process Finishing".

I understand it didn't work because the return was inside the anonymous function, and someLongProcess didn't return any promise at all. And of course I already tried to just put the return after the setTimer block which also failed: "Test A: Process Starting", "Test A: Process Finished", "Test A: Process Finishing".  I've been dorking around with this for hours.  Is there a way to do it?  TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to return `Promise` by using `new Promises()`.

That takes two arguments of first for fulfilled and another for rejection obviously we get in our catch block.

And you can't get `error` in `then` block, it will visible only in `catch` block. Below I have added `isError` argument to simulate that and `seconds` argument for `setTimeout`

More about [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)

```js
async function someLongProcess(myInfoStr,seconds,isError) {
    // Some async process that takes time
    return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
        if(isError){
        return reject("I am an errorrr from "+myInfoStr);
      }
      setTimeout(()=>{
        console.log(myInfoStr + ": Process Finishing");
        resolve(myInfoStr + ": Process Finished")
      }, seconds);
    });
}

const test_1 = "Test A";
console.log(test_1 + ": Process Starting");
someLongProcess(test_1,1000).then(value=>{
  console.log(value);
  return value;
}).catch(error=>{
  console.error(error);
  return error
});
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; }
```

Comment: Thanks.  I guess I thought async function would create and return a promise inherently.

Comment: The [second parameter of `.then()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then#onrejected) _does_ accept a callback expecting the rejection's reason. You do not have to use `.catch()` for this.

Answer (score 1):

[MDN's description for `async`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function#description) reads:

> An `async function` declaration creates an `AsyncFunction` object. Each time when an async function is called, it returns a new `Promise` ... .

This means, your `someLongProcess()` async function *does* return a promise.

But your problem is (as you have correctly identified): The `return` statement returns from the closest function; in this case, your anonymous callback function for `setTimeout()`.

Callback-based functions like `setTimeout()` can be "promisified" by using the `Promise` constructor, to have access to the `resolve` (and `reject`) function of its [`executor` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/Promise#executor).

To "promisify", simply call the callback-based function in the `executor`, and resolve it in the callback-based function's callback:

```js
function timeout(ms) {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(() => resolve(), ms);
  });
}

// Example
console.log("Start");
timeout(2000).then(() => {
  console.log("Finished");
});
```

**Note**: The `async` keyword allows for promises to be `await`ed; the `Promise` constructor provides the `resolve` and `reject` functions. You *can* declare a function as `async` while also using the `Promise` constructor for both benefits; however, in the above example `async` is not necessary.

Using the above `timeout()` async function (async since it returns a promise) allows for a simpler `someLongProcess()` function.

Example with [chained promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise#chained_promises):

```js
function timeout(ms) {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(() => resolve(), ms);
  });
}

// Returns a promise
function someLongProcess(myInfoStr) {
  console.log(myInfoStr + ": Process Starting");
  return timeout(1000).then(() => {
    console.log(myInfoStr + ": Process Finishing");
    return myInfoStr + ": Process Finished";
  });
}

someLongProcess("Test A").then(
  function(value) { console.log(value) },
  function(error) { console.log("Oh oh!: " + error) }
);
```

Example with `async`:

```js
function timeout(ms) {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(() => resolve(), ms);
  });
}

async function someLongProcess(myInfoStr) {
  console.log(myInfoStr + ": Process Starting");
  await timeout(1000);
  console.log(myInfoStr + ": Process Finishing");
  return myInfoStr + ": Process Finished";
}

someLongProcess("Test A").then(
  function(value) { console.log(value) },
  function(error) { console.log("Oh oh!: " + error) }
);
```

---

I was unaware that the `.then()` method accepts a second parameter for a `onRejected` callback. I usually see [`.catch()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/catch) in favour of it, but I guess I learned something from your question as well!

Make sure to learn about the benefits of both `async`/`await` and the `Promise` constructor. Since either approaches return promises, both allow for chained promises.

**For the future**: You should also be aware of [`Promise.all()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) and similar functions, should you want to run multiple async functions in parallel instead of sequentially.